# How to change styling on bootstrap button when save button is disabled?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using btn-btn-primary class of bootstrap for button styling but i have issue when form is invalid button is disabled with light blue color and grayish background that is not making enough difference with when it is enabled. How can i change background color and font in both cases ?

main.html

```
<form name="createProcessFormName" id="createProcessForm" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="panel-body formHeight">
        <!--<p class="text-danger" ng-show="createProcessFormName.$dirty && createProcessFormName.$invalid">{{validationMessage}}</p>-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6 fieldHeight">
                <label for="name" class="col-md-5 required">Business
                Name:</label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
                ng-model="DTO.LongName" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                placeholder="Name" maxlength="1024" name="Name"
                required>
                <p class="text-danger" ng-show="createProcessFormName.processName.$touched && createProcessFormName.processName.$error.required">Business Process Name is required</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

    <button ng-hide="edit" ng-disabled="createFormName.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Use a different colour for valid and invalid? For example, if your form is invalid, change the button to red / default and disable it. That should create enough contrast between an enabled (blue, bright) and disabled (red or grey, light). Besides that, you could override button styles with `.css` included *after* `bootstrap.css`. These are just some suggestions to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Your best alternative would be to use the `:invalid` pseudo-class.

Once the form has all the required fields filled out, the form will no longer be invalid and therefore the button should go back to its normal state.

```css
form + button.btn.btn-primary {
  background: blue;
}
form:invalid + button.btn.btn-primary {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" required />
</form>

<button ng-hide="edit" ng-disabled="createFormName.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response my buttons are outside the form and i used these classes you mentioned in css but i dont see any color effect..

Comment: No luck! where this css is going in bootstrap.css or i can dd it to any css file

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use ng-class https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

which will add css class based on condtion.

When **createFormName.$invalid** is true, it will apply **invalidCssClassName**

from your css.

When **createFormName.$invalid** is false, it will remove **invalidCssClassName**

from your css.

```
<button ng-hide="edit" ng-disabled="createFormName.$invalid" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" type="button" ng-class="{invalidCssClassName:createFormName.$invalid}" ng-click="submit()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Can i get some example based on my code sorry i am still new to AngularJs.. It will be big help thanks

Comment: You can check this video about Angular JS Fundamentals http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes